# Check first Letter of Line in File Uppercase

Tags: python, regex

How would I write a regular expression that checks the first letter on a line in a text file and then put something in front of the character if its uppercase? This is what I have so far:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'(.*)([A-Z])(.*)>')
...
pr = p.sub(r'\1<P>\2</p>', line)
```

Comment: What do you think "ignore case" means?

Comment: Why would you want to use regular expressions for this? It makes no sense to use it in such a situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I write a regular expression that checks the first letter on
>   a line:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^([A-Z])',r'>\1',"Abc")
'>Abc'
>>> re.sub(r'^([A-Z])',r'>\1',"abc")
'abc'
```

Comment: True, but you've been on SO long enough to know that what the OP asks for isn't always what they actually want.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That depends on OP, sometimes even if you give them the best solution they will still end up accepting an answer that they wanted. :) Example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524819/how-extract-items-of-sublists-in-a-one-line-comprehension-in-python
Clearly jon clements's answer was the best one of the lot, but OP choose a less efficient answer.

Answer (score 12):

Regular expressions are not needed here, as you can solve the problem with the built-in [isupper()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) function:

```
if word[0].isupper():
    new_s = "Something in front %s" % word
```

Comment: What would the variable word look like?